# error invalid source option, source is either '1.3' or '1.4': Browserstack integration with Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: browserstack

I am trying to integrate browserstack with azure devops pipelines. I added all the necessary repos to the pom.xml While building the code i am getting below error.   And i am following this link     https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/azure-pipelines#java

I keep on getting the source failure and says 1.3 or 1.4 i am using Jdk 1.8 version. I defined jdk source as 1.8 and jdk target as 1.8

```
 <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.browserstack</groupId>
                    <artifactId>automate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${jdk.source.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.target.version}</target>
                        <complianceLevel>${jdk.source.version}</complianceLevel>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
    
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.CompilationFailedException: AJC compiler errors:
    error invalid source option, source is either '1.3' or '1.4': 1.8
    abort AspectJ Compiler
    
        Usage: <options> <source file | @argfile>..
    
    AspectJ-specific options:
        -inpath <list>      use classes in dirs and jars/zips in <list> as source
                            (<list> uses platform-specific path delimiter)
        -injars <jarList>   use classes in <jarList> zip files as source
                            (<jarList> uses classpath delimiter)
                            deprecated - use inpath instead.
        -aspectpath <list>  weave aspects in .class files from <list> dirs and jars/zip into sources
                            (<list> uses classpath delimiter)
        -outjar <file>      put output classes in zip file <file>
        -outxml             generate META-INF/aop.xml
        -outxmlfile <file>  specify alternate destination output of -outxml
        -argfile <file>     specify line-delimited list of source files
        -showWeaveInfo      display information about weaving
        -incremental        continuously-running compiler, needs -sourceroots
    
    
        at org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.CompilationFailedException.create(CompilationFailedException.java:35)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.AbstractAjcCompiler.execute(AbstractAjcCompiler.java:549)
        at com.browserstack.automate.mojo.AutomateBaseMojo.execute(AutomateBaseMojo.java:114)
        at com.browserstack.automate.mojo.AutomateCompileMojo.execute(AutomateCompileMojo.java:18)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        ... 20 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```